# Not able to reduce number of task in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am not able to reduce number of task . Spark always show 200 tasks in UI. I am not sure but is it because of default minimum partitions while reading data ? I tried all parameters like numPartitions , partitions, minPartitions in my command mentioned below but none of them worked and spark throwing an error like TypeError: csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'partitions' .  I am using spark2. Please assist. Apologies I am not able to format code mention below.

```
df_ord = spark.read.csv(props.get(env, 'input.dir') + "/orders", header=False,inferSchema=True,**numPartitions=10**) \
              .toDF("ord_id", "ord_dt", "cust_id", "ord_status")
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark have a default property spark.sql.shuffle.partitions which is responsible for partitions. The default value of this is 200 that's why you are seeing 200 partitions on UI.

To change this you can pass conf while submitting the job or using below command

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 100)
```

Alternatively you can use repartition or coalesce to reduce the number of partitions as per your requirement.

References:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html

Comment: which part exactly, you think is not correct? @thebluephantom

Comment: There is only 1 part

Comment: @ShubhamJain     spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 100) will create 100 task while processing data. I am asking to reduce number of partition while reading.

Comment: @thebluephantom  do you have any idea how to configure partitions in above format while creating dataframe  ?